# How to specify multiple inter-dependent associated types in swift protocols?

Tags: swift, generics, types, protocols, where-clause

How do I specify multiple associated types in a protocol with added dependencies on their inner associated types? For example:

```
protocol CombinedType
{
    typealias First: FirstType
    typealias Second: SecondType

    var first: First { get }
    var second: Second { get }
}

protocol FirstType
{
    typealias Value
    var value: Value { get }
}

protocol SecondType
{
    type alias Value
    var value: Value { get }
}
```

I need to specify a limitation on the **CombinedType** protocol that would make it so **FirstType.Value == SecondType.Value** much like in a **where** clause in generics.

Without that limitation, the code:

```
func sum<Combined: CombinedType>(combined: Combined) -> Combined.FirstType.Value
{
    return combined.first + combined.second
}
```

produces an error ***Combined.FirstType.Value*** is not compatible with **Combined.SecondType.Value**.

But if I explicitly add the **where** clause to the function, it compiles:

```
func sum<Combined: CombinedType where Combined.FirstType.Value == Combined.SecondType.Value>(combined: Combined) -> Combined.FirstType.Value
{
    return combined.first + combined.second
}
```

The problem is that this **where** needs to be copied everywhere, which produces a ton of boilerplate and it gets even worse when using **CombinedType** inside another protocol, in which case the **where** clause gets larger and larger.

My question is: can I somehow include that limitation in the protocol itself?